# Open camera error and a few warnings on a Flutter project building with Xcode for iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, sharedpreferences, imagepicker

I wanted to test the app for *iOS* and I installed *Xcode*.

The problem is that I have a few buildtime warnings and 2 bugs only on *iOS*.
First, the camera is not opening and I'm receiving this error without any stack trace as you see in the picture below. And the second problem is that images added in shared preferences are not displaying when I rebuild the project.

I see that some functions are not compatible with the deployment target, *12.0* in my case. I don't know *Swift* at all.
I added in ios/Runner/Info.plist these settings:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to camera to capture photos</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to microphone</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to photo library</string>
```

The dependencies are setted to any to match the last stable version.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: any
  shared_preferences: any
  image_collage_widget: any
  screenshot: any
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: any
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: any
  image_gallery_saver: any
  sqflite: any
  path: any
  dropdown_button2: any
  rflutter_alert: any
  animated_widgets: any
  flutter_launcher_icons: any
```

So, why my camera is not opening on *iOS*, how to get rid of these warnings and why my shared preferences images are not rendered on *iOS*?

**Edit**: If I test on real iOS mobile device, the camera is working...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problems:

- the images are now rendering from shared preferences, the problem was that I was saving them as string paths, instead of saving them as *base64strings*.
- the iOS simulator doesn't have a camera as @Ujjawal Maurya said in an answer.

The warnings are still there, but I can ignore them as the app is still running well. It's a good practice to change the deprecated functions, but I don't know Swift at all.

Answer (score 1):

`Warnings:` These are just warnings, you can ignore them. Project will run.
( You can work on those warnings)

`Camera issue:` is because simulator doesn't have camera.

Comment: I think I solved the problem with rendering the images from shared preferences. I will edit tomorrow. How is possible that the simulator doesn't have a camera? Anyway, it's good to hear that. I know that I can ignore warnings, but it's kinda important due to deprecated functions. Can you help me with any of them?